# How to login Laravel with flutter using HTTPRequest

Tags: php, laravel, flutter, httprequest

I have throuble with my program, so I create a Flutter App, And I will create a Login Page, but I want to use laravel to login

Comment: Please add more information, such code you have tried. This question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Fajrul, 
In my opinion you are mixing up some things here. 
Flutter is on the Client side (on your mobile device for that matter). 
And Laravel is the PHP environment which runs on a server.

So, my guess is that you have a Laravel application on the server, maybe a RESTful API build in Laravel. 
And you want Flutter (client side) to log in to PHP-Laravel (server side).

If that is your setup, then your question makes sense.

The answer would be that it totally depends on how you have setup the login-technology on the server-side (in Laravel). 
Do you use Sessions and Cookies? Do you use JWT's? Or do you use something else?

In case of tokens: [take a look here at DidierBoelens.com](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/05/token-based-communication-with-server---part-1/)